# Update nested parameter in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to update nested parameter in document MongoDb:

```
    $this->collection->update(
   ["prototype_id" => $id],
   ["$set" => ["parameters" => $newdata]],
   ["upsert" => true, "multiple" => true]);
```

In result I get error:

> zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?

Where `$newdata` is:

```
array:1 [
  "5920d086470e6cb30e3c986c" => array:1 [
    "Acceleration" => "2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: what's your $id value, and $set value

Comment: Php is trying to interpolate what it thinks is a variable as `"$set"`. Use single quotes to pass the string literal `'$set'`

Comment: It works, but this query insert again new parameters in document, instead updating

Comment: Do I understand right that this query tries to insert data in `parameters` if inserted data `$v` is not exists?

Comment: I try to add only data that is not exists in document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to add/overwrite field in embedded document.

Something like

`$parameter_id = "5920d086470e6cb30e3c986c";`

`['$set' => ["parameters.".$parameter_id => ["Acceleration" => "2"]]];`

Alternatively, define `parameters` as embedded array and you can `$push` to insert whole embedded document.